# Function with a for loop and push method returning 250 arrays of length one instead of single array of length 250

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I’ve created a function named “worldRegion” where I use the push method. Each time I console log the array, where the elements are meant to be pushed into, I’m expecting to see an array of 250 elements. Instead what I’m getting is 250 arrays, each of which containing a single element, which the for loop had iterated over.

According to the definition given by MDN: The push method appends values to an array. Not “arrays”. So I’m guessing something is wrong with my for loop. But I don’t know what.

I looked up my problem on the internet but didn’t get any hits.

```js
const url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
const btn = document.querySelector("button")




  fetch(url)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(data){
    var options  = ''
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      options += `<option value="${data[i].name}">${data[i].name}</option>`
    }
    document.querySelector("select").innerHTML = options
    worldRegion(data)
  })


  function worldRegion(myData) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
      var myArray = []
      myArray.push(myData[i].name)
        console.log(myArray) 
    }
  }

  function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"

> Blockquote

    <title>what language do they speak</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="" name=""></select><br>

  </body>
  <script src="index.js" `enter code here`type="text/javascript">

  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing a new array every time your loop runs. Move your initialization of `myArray` outside of the for loop.

```
  function worldRegion(myData) { 
    var myArray = []; //<--Move this here
    for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
      myArray.push(myData[i].name);
      console.log(myArray);
    }
  }
```

```js
const url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
const btn = document.querySelector("button")




  fetch(url)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(data){
    var options  = ''
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      options += `<option value="${data[i].name}">${data[i].name}</option>`
    }
    document.querySelector("select").innerHTML = options
    worldRegion(data)
  })


  function worldRegion(myData) { 
    var myArray = []
    for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
      myArray.push(myData[i].name)
        console.log(myArray) 
    }
  }

  function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"

> Blockquote

    <title>what language do they speak</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="" name=""></select><br>

  </body>
  <script src="index.js" `enter code here`type="text/javascript">

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to `return` the array also.